# Importing the data base from third party data base to Magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I have a online store in magento.We have to upload  thousands of products  from a third party data base.I want to write a script which can read the product values from the third party data base and can insert those products into my store.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

[Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) is a well known solution for magento product mass import. It has external database connectivity built in. It can also be used as a programmatic import engine through it's datapump API.
See [Wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/) for more information

Answer (score 0):

bMagento comes with a data import feature built in System > Import/Export > Import.

If you would like to programatically create products, there are a fair number of tutorials readily available on the web.  It's quite doable.

Magento's built in indexing can slow the creation of new products programatically, especially when importing large numbers, so third party scripts such as Magmi referenced below exist to speed the import.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options, however you need to be clear on the requirements. If you need just passthrough then Magmi or flat file uploads are fine, however if you need data cleansing or mapping then you need supplier onboarding.

Supplier data onboard maps, cleans, enriches, and loads the data from csv, xml, web services, effectively etl (extract, transform, load). An etl solution can be coded manually however this is fixed in programming and specific to each supplier, plus it takes longer than you think.

Dynamic solutions which can map any dataset are much more complex, we have these, they are designed to be set-and-forget with minimal maintenance. For example, you map your store categories to the supplier categories, remap brands names to your brands, enrich the data with your attributes such as department from the categeory with the files auto-downloaded (if necessary) from the supplier. These solutions are also delta enabled, meaning it only loads changes which are about 1-2% of the supplier data file per day, increasing performance and reducing load on the server.

So it really depands if you need a pass-through or etl based.